# Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'param' [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass the the value contained in param in **LoginViewController.swift** to **NetworkHandler.swift**.

I keep trying, but the value doesn't pass and I get an error. Which is the problem?

I've been trying it since yesterday but still couldn't find a solution. help would be appreciated.

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
var param: String?
@IBOutlet var inputId: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var inputPass: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NetworkHandler.LoginBoard({ LoginList in
        self.LoginList = LoginList
        }, param: param ?? "")
}
@IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
   param = "userId=\(inputId.text ?? "")&userPw=\(inputPass.text ?? "")"
   print("This is Param = ",param!)

let controller = NetworkHandler.LoginBoard(completeHandler: (Login) -> Void, param: param ?? "")
controller.param = param // ERROR [Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'param'

}
```

**NetworkHandler.swift**

```
class func LoginBoard(_ completeHandler: @escaping (Login) -> Void, param: String) {
    let loginboard: String = MAIN_URL + "/member/login"
    guard let url = URL(string: loginboard) else {
      print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    let param = param
    let paramData = param.data(using: .utf8)
}
```

I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You are assigning a method to your `controller` var. `LoginBoard` method returns `Void`. As the error states an empty tuple `()` same as `Void` has no  `param` property.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected The basic syntax is not perfect yet so there are a lot of mistakes. I have corrected the part you informed. Thank you
Then, if the **loginBoard** returns **void**, the **Loginviewcontroller** and property do not match, so you can't pass a value at all?

Comment: your completionHandler should be the last parameter of your LoginBoard method signature.

Comment: What is `controller` suppose to be? For example, inside of `UIView` is a type `frame` so you can do `let view = UIView()` `view.frame = CGRect()`; in your case you do `controller.param = param` well what type is `controller`? I ask because you set `let controller = NetworkHandler.LoginBoard(completeHandler: (Login) -> Void, param: param ?? "")` but `NetworkHandler.LoginBoard` does not return anything. What class is `LoginBoard` suppose to return?